# Split City, State and Zip for All Countries

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

This is probably a common problem which was addressed quite a few times in the past but I couldn't find a solution for this to be implemented in Snowflake and for multiple countries. So, posting it here for expert guidance.

Since my data includes multiple countries, I would like to parse them appropriately. Here is some sample data.

```
CITY_STATE_ZIP 
ANN ARBOR, MI 48104-4000 
Zürich, ZH 8004 
San Diego, CA 92127 
Toronto, ON M5C 3G7
```

Answer (score 1):

Your "zip code" appears to be the last element separated by a space in the `city_state_zip` column.  If so:

```
select regexp_substr(city_state_zip, '[^ ]+$')
```

You can be a little more explicit about the separating space, if you prefer:

```
select regexp_substr(city_state_zip, ' ([^ ]+)$')
```

You can extend this to everything after the comma except for the first part:

```
select regexp_replace(city_state_zip, '.*, [^ ]+ (.+)$', '\1')
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8e94115b51c9bb776ffd4d49994e5739) is a db<>fiddle which uses Oracle which is pretty close to Snowflake in syntax for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon! How do I split the State part here? I tried the following but it gives me the Zipcode as well. SELECT CITY_STATE_ZIP,
  split_part(CITY_STATE_ZIP, ',',  0),
  split_part(CITY_STATE_ZIP, ',',  -1),
  regexp_substr(city_state_zip, ' ([^ ]+)$')

Comment: Also, it isn't working for Canadian or some of the European Zipcodes since they have a space in Zipcodes.

Comment: Julaayi . . . I added another alternative.

Comment: that isn't still working for me. For the Canadian/European zipcodes, it is only returning the last three values instead of 7 values including the space in the zipcode.

Comment: @Julaayi . . . I fixed the expression to use `regexp_replace()` and added a db<>fiddle.

Comment: It is returning this value - box () for all the zipcodes based on the code in fiddle. I used exactly the same values I posted in my original post. I don't see an option to post an image for the same for that box.

Comment: @Julaayi . . . You might have to adjust the third argument to be the proper back-reference for Snowflake.  For instance, it might require `'\\1'`.

Comment: Thank you! That worked. I will post my entire answer just in case someone needs it in future.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the suggestion from Gordon, I ended up with this logic to separate into three columns. Posting it here if this might help someone in future.

```
SELECT  CITY_STATE_ZIP,
        SPLIT_PART(CITY_STATE_ZIP, ',', 0)                              AS CITY,
        SUBSTRING(SPLIT_PART(TRIM(CITY_STATE_ZIP), ',',  -1), 1, 3)     AS STATE,
        regexp_replace(city_state_zip, '.*, [^ ]+ (.+)$', '\\1')        AS ZIP
FROM    foo
```